# Cambiar color a linea de menu

Tags: css

estoy trabajando en una pagina web (wordpress) y deseo cambiar el color de la linea que sale abajo del menu solo cuando estoy parado en esa pagina. ¿Que codigo css es recomendable para cambiarla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo html involucrado, he mirado que tal vez sea con border-buttom-color pero ya lo intente y no me funciono.

```html
<ul id="menu-menu-principal" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right responsive-nav main-nav-list"><li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-29"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com">Inicio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com/planes">Planes</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-26 current_page_item menu-item-35"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com/clases" aria-current="page">Clases</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com/tienda">Tienda</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com/conoce-rmfit">Conoce Rm Fit</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="https://rmfit.000webhostapp.com/blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor lee [ask], serías tan amable de editar y mostrar el código HTML y CSS involucrado? además que has investigado?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione con el siguiente código:

```
#menu-menu-principal li a:before{
    background:blue;
}
```